# Removing event handlers from custom control's template parts

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

When I first started writing WPF custom controls, if I wanted to add an event handler, I would do so in the control's OnApplyTemplate override, after getting the template part:

```
public void override OnApplyTemplate() {
  if ( addMenu != null ) {
    addMenu.Click -= addMenu_Click;
    addMenu = null;
  }
  addMenu = (MenuItem)Template.FindName("PART_AddMenu", this); 
  addMenu.Click += addMenu_Click;
}
```

But then one day I noticed that OnApplyTemplate() is not always called when I'd expect it to be, i.e. when the control is disconnected from the visual tree.  That is, using the above technique, the event handlers won't always be removed.  So I came up with a different way:

```
public MyCustomControl()
{
  Loaded += this_Loaded;
}

void this_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Unloaded += this_Unloaded;

  addMenu = (MenuItem)Template.FindName("PART_AddMenu", this);
  addMenu.Click += addMenu_Click;
}

void this_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Unloaded -= this_Unloaded;

  if (addMenu != null)
  {
    addMenu.Click -= addMenu_Click;
    addMenu = null;
  }
}
```

This way seems to do the trick.  Does everyone concur that this is the better way of hooking up and removing event handlers in a custom control?  If not, then why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is fine, but you do have to understand that you get the unloaded event at times that you might not want the event handlers unhooked.  For example, let's say you have a tab control.  When you switch TabItems the content of the previous TabItem all gets Unloaded and then reloaded when the TabItem becomes selected again.  This is fine for things like Button.Click because you can't perform such actions on an inactive tab, but any events that don't require the item to be loaded into the visual tree will be disconnected even though the items still exist.

Why do you feel you need to clean up all event handlers?  I realize that there are some cases where they can hang onto a reference of another object, but this is an unusual case and is usually best handled by cleaning them up when used in that way.  Here's some better details on this: [How built-in WPF controls manage their event handlers to an attached event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528127/how-built-in-wpf-controls-manage-their-event-handlers-to-an-attached-event)

Comment: You're right that I want to prevent hanging onto references, since I've noticed it happening during performance tuning. I'm unsure of the specific causes, so I'd rather play it safe by using the new technique. Regarding your TabItem example, I know that's what happens but I can't think of a case where it's a problem.

Comment: The leak only occurs if a parent object resolves its event onto a child object (thus keeping a second reference to the child object).

Comment: If I follow you correctly, then in the above example the "parent object" is the custom control and the "child object" is the addMenu (the template part). Since the custom control stores the addMenu in a private field, then a leak could occur in the old technique (that used OnApplyTemplate).

Comment: No.  In your example, the custom control would have to do something like custom.event += addMenu.Method, rather than the usual addMenu.Event += custom.Method.  This is very unusual to do.

Answer (score 1):

WPF controls (such as ComboBox) uses the `OnTemplateChangedInternal()` method to unregister events that are registered in `OnApplyTemplate()`. You can't override that method, as it's internal to the PresentationFramework dll, but you can override the protected `OnTemplateChanged()` method to do the same - it's called by `OnTemplateChangedInternal()` in the Control base class.

Here's sample code that could go into your custom control:

```
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            EditableTextBoxSite = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox;
            EditableTextBoxSite.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(this.OnEditableTextBoxTextChanged);
            this.EditableTextBoxSite.PreviewTextInput -= new TextCompositionEventHandler(this.OnEditableTextBoxPreviewTextInput);
        }

        protected override void OnTemplateChanged(ControlTemplate oldTemplate, ControlTemplate newTemplate)
        {
            base.OnTemplateChanged(oldTemplate, newTemplate);
            if (this.EditableTextBoxSite == null)
                return;
            this.EditableTextBoxSite.TextChanged -= new TextChangedEventHandler(this.OnEditableTextBoxTextChanged);
            this.EditableTextBoxSite.PreviewTextInput -= new TextCompositionEventHandler(this.OnEditableTextBoxPreviewTextInput);
        }
```

I'm not sure about all the implications of doing this, but it does seem to be the closest way to emulate what WPF controls do.