# Removing DataContextChanged/Loaded Event Handlers on XAML User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, datacontext

In efforts to reduce memory leaks, I am attempting to figure out whether, after adding a handler to the "DataContextChanged" event or the "Loaded" event on a XAML User Control, i.e. (UserControl.xaml.cs):

```
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(MyUserControl_DataContextChanged);
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyUserControl_Loaded);
    }
```

If I need to remove it. Does WPF handle this, or do I need to remove them manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer -- no.

You only need to remove handlers when they would keep an object rooted, meaning prevent its garbage collection.  This will not happen if you create a child object and have one of its event handlers point into a parent object, because there are no dangling references to the child object.

It *will* happen if you create a child object and the parent object points one of its event handlers into the child object, because now the parent object has a reference to the child object that will keep it alive (rooted).

In the case you specify above, it's totally internal -- you are adding a reference to your own class, inside the class. When the user control is destroyed, it won't have references sitting around in another class' event handler. So you do not need to remove the event handler.

Comment: The new RoutedEventHandler() part creates a new instance of an object external to the user control. The RoutedEventHandler holds a reference to the user control (since that's what an event handler does) and the user control holds a reference to the RoutedEventHandler (since it keeps a collection of everyone that has registered). So they reference each other, meaning both objects are kept alive. So I disagree with your statements.

Comment: @Nick, your assertions are not correct.  += RoutedEventHandler does not create a new, external object holding a reference to the class.  If you do not believe this, use a CLR profiler.  You'll see the pattern above does not cause a rooted object.

Comment: @Nick, please see the answer here for a more thorough explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528127/how-built-in-wpf-controls-manage-their-event-handlers-to-an-attached-event

Comment: is this documented and guaranteed behaviour?

Comment: It is.  Look up in .NET how garbage collection works.